# How is default-terminal compared to tmux terminal-overrides

Tags: tmux

In my tmux config I have the following:

```
set-option -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ',*-256color*:Tc'
```

which means that if I run `tmux info | grep Tc` to check for truecolor support, it works and says Enabled. `echo $TERM` inside tmux gives `screen-256color` as expected.

As I understand from the tmux manual, terminal-overrides matches the terminal name on `*-256color*`, which makes sense.

**However, what I don't understand** is that the following does **not** work/match:

```
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ',*screen-256color*:Tc'
```

**I can't see why not? What's going on?**

tmux version 2.9a

(aside: if you're wondering why I'm using `screen-` instead of, say `tmux-` it's because neovim seems to require it to detect truecolor support)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They are entirely separate and `default-terminal` is never checked against `terminal-overrides`.

`default-terminal` is the default used for `TERM` inside tmux, so should match `screen*` or `tmux*`. This tells applications inside tmux what the capabilities are for tmux itself.

`terminal-overrides` matches `TERM` outside tmux and allows you to modify the capabilities tmux uses when it talks to the terminal it is running it.

Presumably `*-256color` matches because you have `TERM` outside set to something that matches that but doesn't match `screen-256color*` (probably `xterm-256color`).

If you want the equivalent for `terminal-overrides` for applications inside tmux (modifying capabilities of the terminfo(5) entry inside tmux), you will need to either look for configuration options in the applications you are using, or build your own entry based on `tmux-256color` or `screen-256color` using infocmp(1) and tic(1).

Comment: awesome, thanks for that! The whole world of terminals is one of those things that I don't *want* to have to care about, and thankfully most the time they Just Work, but when they don't it's such a PITA trying to get to grips with *why*! It's a bit like character encoding, great when it's working, nightmare when it's not! Very clear explanation, thanks.